At compile time, determine smallest (unsigned) integer type fitting a value
I want a smallest_unsigned_fitting_t that can do this (or similar syntax):
constexpr std::size_t a = 42

// Here, `smallest_unsigned_fitting<a>` should become `std::uint8_t`.
// If, e.g., `a = 513`, then it should instead become `std::uint16_t`, etc.
constexpr std::array<smallest_unsigned_fitting_t<a>, 1234> arr{};


Using C++20 is fine, so std::in_range is available. It seems like something using templates and maybe SFINAE should work.
Any ideas how to approach this? Thanks in advance!
probably not useful, but here is my attempt which DOES NOT WORK:
// THIS DOES NOT WORK!

template <std::size_t n,
        typename = void>
struct smallest_fitting_unsigned {
    using type = void;
};

template <std::size_t n>
struct smallest_fitting_unsigned<n, 
    std::enable_if_t<std::in_range<std::uint8_t>(n), std::uint8_t>> {
    using type = std::uint8_t;
};

template <std::size_t n>
struct smallest_fitting_unsigned<n,
    std::enable_if_t<std::in_range<std::uint16_t>(n), std::uint16_t>> {
    using type = std::uint16_t;
};

/// etc.

template<std::size_t n>
using smallest_fitting_unsigned_t = smallest_fitting_unsigned<n>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<smallest_fitting_unsigned_t<42>, void>); // does not fail :(


Are C++20 concepts acceptable?

Related/dupe: Find the smallest integer type that can count up to N

@user12002570 The linked question asks specifically about C++03, while this question seems to be about C++20.

I added another solution to the dupe
